# ng-grid with no vertical bars

Tags: angularjs, templates, ng-grid

Trying to remove vertical bars between columns in ng-grid.

I grabbed the default rowTemplate, removed the div, and put it in gridOptions:

```
rowTemplate: '<div ng-style="{ \'cursor\': row.cursor }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell {{col.cellClass}}"><div ng-cell></div></div>',
```

which actually works, but how do I do the same for the header?

There's certainly some functionality for it:

```
<div class="ngVerticalBar ngVerticalBarVisible" ng-style="{height: col.headerRowHeight}" ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }" style="height: 30px;">&nbsp;</div>
```

but how do I access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this?

```
        headerRowTemplate: '<div ng-style="{ height: col.headerRowHeight }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngHeaderCell"><div ng-header-cell></div></div>',
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SNu96QWPoPSr38QUhjLL?p=preview)

Comment: OK, well that works. :P

I had tried that (should have posted it as well) and it had not taken. I must have misspelled it or something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could add the below code in your custom css file:

```
.ngVerticalBar 
{
    width: 0px;
}
```

i.e. In the latest version of ui-grid(ng-grid), the code should be:

```
.ui-grid-cell 
{
    border-right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could *edit your answer* and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: Thanks Taryn, I've changed my answer.