# UI-Grid Remove Column Spacing. Make 2 Columns Look Like 1

Tags: angular-ui-grid

How can I remove the separator line between two columns to make them look as if they are one column.

Comment: check out this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297110/ng-grid-with-no-vertical-bars

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297110/ng-grid-with-no-vertical-bars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added css class

```
.border-whiteNoWidth
{
  border-right: 0px !important;

}
```

Then added this to the `cellClass` of the specific column